# Stripe deauthorize webhook to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

The question goes like this:

I have connected a user with Stripe through my Rails app, and such user is connected via API key.

In Stripe there is an option to `deauthorize` API keys. I would like to be informed in my app once a user `deauthorizes` my API key. I know it is possible, or should be possible.

I know I have to manage webhooks in my app, but I am wondering where to set which URL of my app Stripe will call when user `deauthorizes` my API key, and what data will be sent to my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) are used by Stripe to notify your server of events. There are two types of webhook endpoints you can set up:

- "Account" endpoints will receive events that happen on your own account
- "Connect" endpoints will receive events that happen on accounts that are connected to yours via Stripe Connect

In a nutshell, you'll configure an URL to your own server (the "endpoint") in your Stripe [webhook settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/webhooks). Whenever an event happens, Stripe will send an [event object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_object) to that URL.

In the case of Connect endpoints, the object will also have an [`account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks) attribute with the ID of the account that emitted the event.

To be notified of deauthorizations, you'd need to set up a Connect endpoint and catch [`account.application.deauthorized`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-account.application.deauthorized) events. The data you will receive will look like this:

```
{
  "created": 1326853478,
  "livemode": false,
  "id": "evt_00000000000000",
  "type": "account.application.deauthorized",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "api_version": "2016-03-07",
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "ca_00000000000000",
      "object": "application",
      "name": "Your Application"
    }
  },
  "account": "acct_00000000000000"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but just wanted to be more clear. I don't want for the each individual user to set webhooks in their accounts. I would like my app to be notified once a user deauthorizes the API key that is connected with my app https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/applications . I am wondering what URL should I create in my app so it will catch such events?

Comment: That's what a Connect endpoint is for. You set the endpoint once, on your own account (the platform), and you'll receive the events from all connected accounts. The connected accounts themselves don't need to configure an endpoint.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The Connected endpoint is located in my "app" on stripe, sort of the speaking.  Ok, that answers the question about the URL. I will set it as answered, but just a side-question, the stripe will send a `user_id` to my webhook, but I don't remember ever saving that actual id in the user's table. How can I identify the user who was deauthorized in my app in that case using stripe's `user_id`?

Comment: At the end of the OAuth flow: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/reference#post-token-response, you get the account ID in the `stripe_user_id` field. You should save it in your database at that time.
You can also use the "list all accounts" API call to retrieve the list of accounts that are already connected to your platform: https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_accounts.

Comment: Magnificent! Thanks a lot for all the information! It helps a lot!

Comment: I'm confused. Why would we get a user_id parameter on the *connect* webhook when we already have the account property of the Event delivered via this webhook? The user_id would make sense on a platform webhook since we otherwise don't know which account deauthorized our app. I emailed Stripe about this since it doesn't really make sense at the moment.

Comment: @nickdnk The parameter used to be called `user_id`. It's now called `account` on recent API versions (https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2017-05-25). I've updated the answer above to be up-to-date.

Comment: Yes, I found that out after contacting Stripe. Thanks for keeping your answer updated.